# Ag-grid export (Excel styles): export of one table overriding the styling/formatting of another table export

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have 2 ag-grid table components in my project with each of them having their own export and excel styles(numberformat, bold etc., ).

If I export the table ag-grid-1 and then export table ag-grid-2 (or vice versa) then some of the stylings(like numberformatting, bold etc.;) from ag-grid-1 styles are getting applied to the data of ag-grid-2.

Below are the steps mentioning when the styling gets overridden and when it doesn't

**Styling gets Overridden**:

- Step 1: open the application and export table ag-grid-1.
- Step 2: export table ag-grid-2.

-Styling of ag-grid-2 excel export overridden by styling of ag-grid-1.

**Styling doesn't get Overridden**:

- Step 1: open the application and export table ag-grid-1.
- Step 2: Reload application.
- Step 3: Export table ag-grid-2.

-Styling of ag-grid-2 doesn't get overridden and stays as we defined.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Expected result: exporting of one table shouldn't override the styling of another table export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, you must install the `new` version of ag-grid.  They addressed this issue `(AG-2981)` with a fix on `v21.0.0`. The excel export styles sheets are not being cleared when there is two tables on the same page with export capabilities.